# Calculating Amounts of of varied DropDown

Tags: jquery, dropdown

I have an individual varying number of DropDown Menus. 
The count depends on how many categories are saved in the Database.

Here is one Select section:

```
<select style="text-align:center;" class="field" id="dropDown1">
    <option value="0,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,667" rel="667">Personen</option>
    <option value="1,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,667" rel="667">1</option>
    <option value="2,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,667" rel="667">2</option>
    <option value="3,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,667" rel="667">3</option>
    <option value="4,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,667" rel="667">4</option>
    <option value="5,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,667" rel="667">5</option>
    <option value="6,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,667" rel="667">6</option>
    <option value="7,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,667" rel="667">7</option>
    <option value="8,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,667" rel="667">8</option>
    <option value="9,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,667" rel="667">9</option>
    <option value="10,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,667" rel="667">10</option>
</select>
```

Above there is a loop and produce a number of this select sections.
Each select has an id="dropDown"+ an individual number

The rel Attribute is the Amount of each option.

Now to my Question:
The User should choose a number of each select and then i need the amount multiplied with the number selected. Then the sum of all.

Example:

I have 3 Dropdown.
Dropdown1: Amount 260, Option: 2
Dropdown2: Amount 200, Option: 1
Dropdown3: Amount 300, Option: 0

Then I need a Span with the total amount: 720

How would I calculate that?

Here is the site with my dropdown:
Visit http://fischwenger.derquerdenker.at/safe/book_reise_buchen.php

Comment: What is the point of having the price duplicated in the rel? Also why have the same price on each option? If you do not offer quantum rebate, have the price as a data attribute on the select

Comment: no there is no rebate. It's for room-booking. there are a different count of categories. in each category you can book 1 to 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

I see `'1'.",".$kat.",".$preis;` in your value

If you have 1,something,200, then change 
`$(this).attr("value")` to `parseInt($(this).attr("value"))` or perhaps

`$(this).attr("value").split(",")[0]`

If you have the price in the value too, you do not need the rel="preis"
If you have the price in the rel, you do not need it in the value.

In any case the code will look like this

```js
$(function() {
  $(".field").on("change", function() {
    var total = 0;
    $("select.field option:selected").each(function() {
      var val = $(this).attr("value").split(",")[0];
      if (val && !isNaN(val)) {
        var price = $(this).attr("rel");
        total += val * price;
      }
    });
    $("#total").text(total.toFixed(2));
  })
  .change(); // trigger onload
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="field select medium" tabindex="11" name="absender_" class="required"> 
  <option value=""></option> 
  <option value="Frau">Frau</option> 
  <option value="Herr">Herr</option> 
</select><br/>

<select style="text-align:center;" class="field" id="dropDown1">
  <option value="0,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,667" rel="667">Personen</option>
  <option value="1,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,667" rel="667">1</option>
  <option value="2,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,667" rel="667">2</option>
  <option value="3,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,667" rel="667">3</option>
  <option value="4,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,667" rel="667">4</option>
  <option value="5,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,667" rel="667">5</option>
  <option value="6,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,667" rel="667">6</option>
  <option value="7,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,667" rel="667">7</option>
  <option value="8,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,667" rel="667">8</option>
  <option value="9,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,667" rel="667">9</option>
  <option value="10,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,667" rel="667">10</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select style="text-align:center;" class="field" id="dropDown2">
  <option value="0,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,599" rel="599">Personen</option>
  <option value="1,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,599" rel="599">1</option>
  <option value="2,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,599" rel="599">2</option>
  <option value="3,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,599" rel="599">3</option>
  <option value="4,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,599" rel="599">4</option>
  <option value="5,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,599" rel="599">5</option>
  <option value="6,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,599" rel="599">6</option>
  <option value="7,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,599" rel="599">7</option>
  <option value="8,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,599" rel="599">8</option>
  <option value="9,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,599" rel="599">9</option>
  <option value="10,Pro Person im Einzelzimmer,599" rel="599">10</option>
</select>
<br/>Abfahrtsort:
<select class='field' name='abfahrtsort' id='abfahrtsort'>
  <option value='0' rel="0">Bitte wählen Sie Ihren Abfahrtsort</option>
  <option value="0,busbahnhof,0" rel="0">Busbahnhof - 0 €</option>
  <option value="0,garage_fischwenger_carport,0" rel="0">Garage FISCHWENGER (Carport) - 0 €</option>
  <option value="0,bh_bei_gh_drei_eichen,0" rel="0">BH bei GH Drei Eichen - 0 €</option>
  <option value="0,friedburg_baeckerei_heinzl,0" rel="0">Friedburg Bäckerei HEINZL - 0 €</option>
  <option value="0,munderfing_gemeindeamt,0" rel="0">Munderfing Gemeindeamt - 0 €</option>
</select>
<br/>zubuchbare Optionen:
<select class='field' name='optionen' id='optionen'>
  <option value='0' rel="0">Optionen</option>
  <option value="1,bahnfahrt_auf_das_jungfernjoch" rel="85">Bahnfahrt auf das Jungfernjoch - 85 €</option>
</select>
<br/>
<span id="total"></span>
```

This can all be made simpler, but then I will have to start charging you :)

Comment: thank you, 
one question. where is the function? directly above the select?

Comment: You mean where to put the code? In the head in its own script tags after the jquery script tag.

Comment: I put it there. But the Total is always "NaN"
I'm really sorry.

Comment: Your jquery is FAR too old. Please change to `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you. I took you simpler code. but nothing happened.

Comment: Because you call everything field. Please see my update. You also need to swap the price on the `Abfahrtsort: <select class='field' name='abfahrtsort' id='abfahrtsort'><option value='0'>Bitte wählen Sie Ihren Abfahrtsort</option><option value=busbahnhof,0>Busbahnhof - 0 €</option>` to `Abfahrtsort: <select class='field' name='abfahrtsort' id='abfahrtsort'><option value='0'>Bitte wählen Sie Ihren Abfahrtsort</option><option value="0,busbahnhof">Busbahnhof - 0 €</option>` Ditto  zubuchbare Optionen and Please note I call my field id="total" and not "total_options"

Comment: I did it. But there is no changing.

Comment: Actually - should the bahnfart not be for all persons, times 85? I added rel to every select's option

Comment: No not really. This I have to recode.
Bahnfahrt should be no option, instead there I will make a select for the persons like for the rooms.

Comment: Ok, just code it the same way as the rooms - like I did in my example, and my code will work assuming you also change to <span id="total" and change the jQuery version

Comment: I did all changes. But it doesn't still work. I don't know whats wrong.

Comment: I've seen that the class "field" automatically changes in "field valid" is this maybe the problem?

Comment: Yes I did! But no changes. The result is always NaN

Comment: Because you now have ANOTHER field: `<select class="field select medium" tabindex="11" name="absender_" class="required">

                        <option value=""></option>

                        <option value="Frau">Frau</option>

                        <option value="Herr">Herr</option>

                    </select>` - perhaps we can find a better class name for our fields that needs to be calculated?

Comment: Wow. So cool!!! This was the mistake.!
Thanks a lot! Just one Question. At the room choose, how can I count the persons ? because I just want to show the number of Options at the Bahnfahrt.

Comment: See updated code that can handle your `class="field"` now

Comment: Yes of course. Thank you.
For the counting Problem, do I have open a new thread?

Comment: What do you mean by counting? You have counting in the `val` - what do you need to do with it for the bahnfahrt? Multiply with the number of people as I suggested?

Comment: No, for example:
the users choose 2 persons for Doppelzimmer and 1 Person for Einzelzimmer. Total they are 3 Persons. Then I will also give the possibility to choose MAX. 3 persons at the Bahnfahrt Select.

Comment: Yeah, that is a different question.

Comment: What if they want a friend not staying with them to go on the bahnfart?

Comment: no that's not possible. Just people who are staying there can buy a bahnfahrt. ;-)

Comment: Now the Script is starting on the OnChange event. Is it possible also start it when i visit the site?

Because if I go back it should also calculate.

Comment: I added `.change(); // trigger onload`

Comment: Thank you!! Easy but effective. :-) Now I'm working on the problem that the maximum number of select options the sum of the people is. Do you have any hints to solve my problem?

Comment: I might. It is custom coding so perhaps send me an email - my address is in my profile